# Is there a way to override the connection timeout when upgrading site from CMS 6 R2 to 7?

Tags: episerver

I'm having a problem upgrading a site from CMS 6 R2 to 7. I'm getting a wait timeout error while upgrading using the Deployment Center.

I already tried to add the following configuration in C:\Program Files (x86)\EPiServer\Shared\Install\EPiServerInstall.exe.config:

```
 <appSettings>
  <add key="commandTimeout" value="600"/>
 </appSettings>
```

but no avail.

As much as I don't want to resort to manual upgrade, is there a way to override the connection timeout?

Thanks in advance for any help.

***Edit:***

Upgrade log (too long so I cut it just to display the error message):

```
....
Executing database script "C:\Program Files (x86)\EPiServer\CMS\7.0.586.1\Upgrade\Database\sql\0007_0000_0041_0000to0007_0000_0147_0000.sql"
An error has occured and the transaction will be rolled back
Rolledback
The wait operation timed out
The wait operation timed out

An unhandled error has occured:
The wait operation timed out
When executing
At C:\Program Files (x86)\EPiServer\CMS\7.0.586.1\Upgrade\System Scripts\Upgrad
e Site Database (SqlServer).ps1:9 char:2
+     Execute-EPiSqlSvrScript -EPiServerScript -ScriptPath $file -SqlServerName
 $dbCo ...
+    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~

=
Get-EPiIsBulkInstalling
At C:\Program Files (x86)\EPiServer\CMS\7.0.586.1\Upgrade\System Scripts\Upgrade Site Database (SqlServer).ps1:9 char:2
+     Execute-EPiSqlSvrScript -EPiServerScript -ScriptPath $file -SqlServerName $dbCo ...
+    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation timed out
   at EPiServer.Install.InstallationManager.Install(Installer installer)
   at EPiServer.Install.SqlServer.SqlServerInstallationManager.ExecuteDatabaseScript(String sqlServerName, Nullable`1 sqlServerPort, String databaseName, String loginName, String loginPassword, String scriptFilePath, Boolean avoidDbTransaction, Boolean isEPiServerScript, IDictionary parameters)
   at EPiServer.Install.SqlServer.Cmdlets.ExecuteSqlScriptCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
   at System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet.DoProcessRecord()
   at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restarted the site then refreshed the site in DC and it worked now. Looks like the settings are cached in DC.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken (been a while since I used Deployment Center) it uses the connectionstring from web.config for the site and in that you can define timeout.

See example here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I've set both connection timeouts in web.config and EPiServerInstall.exe.config but still not working.

Comment: Do you get any message on what is the course of the timeout. Any detailed error messages?

Comment: First, Make shore you do not have anything else running against the site you upgrade.
If you still get it, start management studio and activity monitor to see who is accessing the database

Comment: Nope, no one's using the db

Comment: I would try to run the script that does the hanging manually to see if you can get more information on what happens.
C:\Program Files (x86)\EPiServer\CMS\7.0.586.1\Upgrade\Database\sql\0007_0000_0041_0000to0007_0000_0147_0000.sql

Comment: I actually tried it, that particular stored proc took 2+ hours to run. What DC does is skip the SPs when they are already executed. With the particular case of that SP, DC is unable to skip it for less than 30 secs then display a time out error.

Comment: Ok, strange. Is it a big database?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77621/discussion-between-henrik-fransas-and-jen).

Comment: Update: I tried to restart the site before doing the upgrade again. This time looks like I'm not getting the error. Looks like the settings are cached in DC.